# The data that is called in chart does not match the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, chart.js

I using chartjs and i tried to make a chart from the database but when I managed to call the data, it didn't match the one in the database.

**My database**

[image: My database]

**And this is for the script**

**Controller**

```
function index(){
    $this->data['graph'] = $this->profit->graph();
    $this->load->view('admin/v_dashboard',$this->data);
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php
class Profit extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }


public function graph()
{
    $data = $this->db->query("SELECT * from profit");
    return $data->result();
}
```

}

**view**

```
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/chart/chart.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
        labels: [
          <?php
            if (count($graph)>0) {
              foreach ($graph as $data) {
                echo "'" .$data->APIID ."',";
              }
            }
          ?>
        ],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Profit',
            backgroundColor: '#ADD8E6',
            borderColor: '##93C3D2',
            data: [
              <?php
                if (count($graph)>0) {
                  foreach ($graph as $data) {
                    echo $data->Jan19 . ", ";
                  }
                }
              ?>
            ]
        }]
    },
});

  </script>
```

**And this is the result**

[image: The view]

in the results there are bakoel has 762 profit whereas in the database he has 0

Comment: The part where you select your data is missing completely.

Comment: sorry I forgot to write it now you can see it again I have edited it

Comment: That's not a database. Perhaps it's a table, but it looks more like an excerpt from a spreadsheet

Comment: I imported it from Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your data - in the beginning, I was wondering where your systems even gets the `762` from. If you take a look at your table, you'll see that `ARINDO` has the value `9,364,762,121` at the index `3` and that `,` is your entry delimiter. So we have 2 more commas in here, meaning that the 5th value becomes `762`. You have to replace the , in your  `echo $data->Jan19 . ", ";` call:

```
 echo str_replace(",","",$data->Jan19). ", ";
```

Comment: thanks its work. but can i change `",",""` with `",","."`  because when I tried the chart it didn't even appear

Comment: You cant do that because that isn't a valid number anymore - you can however add the comma back to the display value. Just search for chart js thousand separator

Comment: Oke Thank you for the help

Comment: Unfortunately @Rifa'i, I fear you're heading very much in the wrong direction - at least, as far as the proper use of an RDBMS is concerned